# How to insert multiple linebreaks in Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, markdown, editing-help, formatting

I've been updating my Stack Exchange profile, and I want to insert a lot(~30) line breaks. I know it's pretty weird.

Here's what I do:

```
text
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>......
another text
```

But the `<br>` takes a lot of space, is there any methods to shorten those?

Comment: Why not use CSS instead?

Comment: Can I embed CSS in Stack Exchange profile? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: If `<br/>` works then I suppose CSS too should work

Comment: Maybe. I'm not an expert on HTML and CSS.

Comment: Did some experiment, turns out Stack Exchange profile doesn't support CSS well. At least I can't embed my CSS into it.

Comment: Why do you want so many line breaks...?

Comment: @Makoto I'm making like an  "interactive" thingy in my profile. You can check it out on my profile.

Comment: Usually people are more creative and actually write applications in their profile.  Especially on mobile, I'm no real fan of having to scroll so much for so little.

Comment: @Makoto I understand what you say, but my ability is not enough to write HTML programs yet.

Comment: Simply use LESS <br/>'s .. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine and the only feasible way to achieve what you want.

The supported markdown / HTML is limited to a strict set. You can force an `<br>` tag by adding two spaces at the end on an line. But that doesn't work on a line that only has whitespace. You can't use CSS either.

In regard to your *takes a lot of space* keep in mind that is probably only a concern for you, the editor, as it makes editing maybe a bit clumsy in the online-editor. The aboutme field allows 30,000 characters (didn't check but the backingfield in the database is nvarchar(max) so that can handle 2GB) so you can add lots of `<br>` before the system starts to bark at you.

Find the limited set of allowed HTML on MSE:

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

For standard markdown there is [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and the [advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

To get a deeper understanding of what the allowed HTML could do for you see [Mozilla Developer Network/HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)